# presented ModalView gets displayed within the custom view, from which its called

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, custom-view

[image]

The above picture shows the schema of my app .. I created a custom view to show the content in UIViewController3 in 1 and 2.

I want to jump directly to VC4 when custom view is touched in VC1 and 2 ..

the custom view was a UIView, the I changed it to UIControl in Interface Builder, to receive touch event ..

I used the following code in custom view class touchevent method

```
    - (IBAction)customViewTouched:(id)sender {

        VC4 *nextController = [[VC4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC4" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextController];

       [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

        navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"My Title";



        navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
 initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
        navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = FALSE;

       // navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"back";

    }
```

---

1. when custom view was touched in VC2(its getting called correctly) - VC4 pops , but only within the custom view..
2. Also I cant get a back button on the navigation bar. ( as suggested in other stackoverflow answers I also tried setting the custom view's title in ViewDidLoad)

3.I create a dummy UIButton in VC1 of customView's size and place the customView in it .. so that I can handle touch event on VC1 itself .. will this create any performance issues ?

```
[myCustomViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myEventHandler) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

when I use the above code, its not throwing any error, but the method myEventHandler never gets called .. in addTarget instead of 'self' when I use 'UIViewController' class name, its throwing an error..

I dont know how to proceed on this .. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

### I assume the unmentioned VC3 manages your custom view:

change [self presentVC] to [self.parentVC presentVC]

the VC3 you are presenting VC4 from is embedded as a child in VC1 and VC2

Comment: [self.parentViewController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];  I tried this , but nothing happens ..

Comment: cant we deal with the touch event on the customview in VC1 itself ? I mean without sending the call back to customview class' - (IBAction)customViewTouched:(id)sender method.. also FYI i stacked 10 customviews inside a scrollView with pageControll

Comment: or shall I create a dummy UIButton in VC1 of customView's size and place the customView in it .. so that I can handle touch event on VC1 itself .. will this create any performance issues ?